# How to configure gradle with testng, package already imported but getting error?

Tags: selenium, gradle, testng, build.gradle

I am newbie towards Gradle. I am able to run my test cases through testng but unable to run with Gradle from eclipse.

Following is the **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = 'selenium.webdriver.qa'

repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.4'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.+'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '2.+'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.+'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.0.+'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.0.+'
}

test {
    useTestNG(){
        include "com.mca.automation.script.SanityTestScript"
    }
}

test.testLogging {
    showStandardStreams = true
}
```

When i run the test class. It shows following error:

```
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:4: error: package org.testng does not exist
import org.testng.Assert;
                 ^
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:5: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
                             ^
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:6: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
                             ^
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
                             ^
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    @BeforeTest
     ^
  symbol:   class BeforeTest
  location: class MCA_SanityTestScript
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class MCA_SanityTestScript
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    @AfterTest
     ^
  symbol:   class AfterTest
  location: class MCA_SanityTestScript
D:\Project\SanityTestScript.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
        Assert.assertTrue(expEvent.equalsOnActiveUntilDate(actualEvent));
        ^
  symbol:   variable Assert
  location: class SanityTestScript
8 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I am not able to understand, exactly what i am doing wrong. Even the testng package is already imported. Using Eclipse, so testng library added to project.

Comment: Can you please check whether the open braces of dependencies (first appearance) are closed?

Comment: yes they are closed and are in right paranthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Your build fails during `compileJava` task. This means that you have your test classes, the one which uses TestNG, in you `src/main/java` folder, in the main sourceset. They should be in `src/test/java` folder, in test sourceset.

You have added TestNg library to the `testCompile` configuration, which is correct. But it also means that this library is added to the classpath only for test compilation and running. Not for compilation and running of your main application. And you seem to have test classes among your application classes.