# testng from github with gradle and jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, gradle, testng

I am using TestNG framework for the automation of my project. I have commited my project on GitHub and want to configure it on Jenkins for continuous integration. I am unable to run the tests using gradle. I have two test classes and i am using this build.gradle,

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

test {
useTestNG()
options.suites("src/main/resources/testng.xml")
}
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', 
version: '3.5.3'
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.11'
testCompile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian.testng', name: 'arquillian-
testng-container', version: '1.1.13.Final'

}
```

Comment: what is the issue, can you provide stack trace

Comment: i use gradle test in terminal and getting this
 _italic_ **bold** /home/mfaheem/WORK/WIND/Projects/EndToEnd/src/main/java/LoggedUserTest.java:3: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
import org.testng.annotations.*;
^
/home/mfaheem/WORK/WIND/Projects/EndToEnd/src/main/java/NewUserTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    @BeforeClass
     ^
  symbol:   class BeforeClass
  location: class NewUserTest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031758/how-to-configure-gradle-with-testng-package-already-imported-but-getting-error/47155816?noredirect=1#comment81260883_47155816

Comment: I added the link for similar question but its not clear about the configuration of jenkins